# android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

Tags: java, android, testing

I'm working with espresso test for my project. I want to check LinearLayout Background color.
I use the following code but is not working and recieve this error :

android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

Thanks if anyone can help

```
public static Matcher<View> withBgColor(final int color) {
        Checks.checkNotNull(color);
        return new BoundedMatcher<View, LinearLayout>(LinearLayout.class) {
            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(LinearLayout row) {
                return color == ((ColorDrawable) row.getBackground()).getColor();
            }
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("with text color: ");
            }
        };
    }
```

and here is my code in espersso test

```
    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.device_linearLayout)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withBgColor(R.drawable.background_transparent_list)));
```

Comment: On what exactly is based your assumption that the `row.getBackground()` returns an instance of `ColorDrawable`?

Comment: How did you set the background of LinearLayout before executing these lines of codes? The output depends on the type of object in setBackground().

Answer (score 1):

There are few objects whose can be output of `getBackground()`.
For example Drawable, VectorDrawable, ColorDrawable and so on.
Therefore, first step is recognizing the type of output. For doing that you can use the code below:

```
row.getBackground().getClass().getSimpleName();
```

The output of above code shows the type of the Drawable. After that you can decide appropriate class for casting it.